# no webhook calls with subscription in paypal sandbox mode

Tags: paypal, sandbox, subscription

With php and curl i create billing plans, subscriptions, get the paypal link and proceed to the payment. Everything works and i get the following webhook calls :

1. Billing plan created
2. Billing subscription created
3. Billing subscription activated
4. Paiement sale completed

So far so good. The problem is that i specified the subscription to a renewal of 1 DAY so i could check what happens when a new regular payment arrives... and nothing.

I don't know if the sandbox does not implement a real subscription with all the correct webhook callback of if i'm doing something wrong. I would be pretty pissed to be forece to develop that in production mode !

Any ideas ?

Any ideas how to test the recurring payment ?

Here is the data i get from paypal API when i call billing_subscription:
You can view it properly on https://jsoneditoronline.org/

```json
{
    "billing_cycles": [
        {
            "frequency": {
                "Interval_count": 1,
                "interval_unit": "DAY"
            },
            "pricing_scheme": {
                "create_time": "2021-08-11T13:47:42Z",
                "fixed_price": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": "2.0"
                },
                "update_time": "2021-08-11T13:47:42Z",
                "version": 1
            },
            "sequence": 1,
            "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
            "total_cycles": 120
        }
    ],
    "create_time": "2021-08-11T13:47:42Z",
    "description": "offre Basic TEST avec un debit tous les jours",
    "id": "P-8AF2870811319631YMEJ5J7Q",
    "links": [
        {
            "encType": "application/json",
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-8AF2870811319631YMEJ5J7Q",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "self"
        },
        {
            "encType": "application/json",
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-8AF2870811319631YMEJ5J7Q",
            "method": "PATCH",
            "rel": "edit"
        },
        {
            "encType": "application/json",
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-8AF2870811319631YMEJ5J7Q/deactivate",
            "method": "POST",
            "rel": "self"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Offre Basic TEST JOUR PAR JOUR",
    "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
        "payment_failure_threshold": 3,
        "service_type": "PREPAID",
        "setup_fee": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "0.0"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE"
    },
    "product_id": "abonnement-test-basic",
    "quantity_supported": false,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "taxes": {
        "inclusive": false,
        "percentage": "20.0"
    },
    "update_time": "2021-08-11T13:47:42Z",
    "usage_type": "LICENSED"
}
```

Comment: You don't provide any details about your Plan creation or Subscription creation requests and responses, nor information on any expected payment is visible in the receiving Sandbox account, nor information on the webhooks you have received. So I'm not sure what kind of help you're hoping to get.

Comment: The problem is not regarding the plan creation (which work perfectly), nor the subscription creation (which also works perfectly). The webhooks works also. I receive perfecftly well the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED call.

My concern is that though my billing plan is set to ONE DAY, i don't have any recurring webhook calls. I am assuming that each day i would receive a call saying that the paiement succeeded.

Comment: You say it's all working perfectly and yet it's not giving the result you want and you provide none of the above (required) information for troubleshooting potential causes

Comment: I updated my question with the data i have of the billing plans.

Well, my question would rather be : aren't i supposed to receive a webhook event everytime the subscription cycle is done (each day in my example) ?
I haven't seen any details about that in the paypal api doc. I'm really confused.

Comment: You commented while i was adding the data in my question :-)

Comment: Well that's a start, looks like the plan schedule should be good -- but when was the transaction? What webhook did you receive? Have you waited at least 24 hours before expecting another?

Comment: I did not receives any webhook after the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED one and i waited 7 days :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (sort-of...)

In production mode, when a recurring paiement is done on a subscription a webhook is called with the event : PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

In sandbox mode, the event is either not sent, either randomly sent days later after when it's supposed to be.